# Retrieving text from an email in a windows form application NOT asp.net

Tags: c#, email, text, input

I'm currently looking for a way to start an application that would take an email text, it would essentially have a link that would allow the email user to click a link and it gets submitted to the database. Of my choice. Or I would want a Windows Form Application that accesses an email that then takes the text of the email and sends it to the database.

Comment: And what is the exact problem with what you tried?

Comment: I can't figure out how to import text from an email. Say the email in my browser window says hello, and I want my application to somehow take the word hello and send it to a database.

Comment: Are you using a browser control to get the email? Or are you receiving the email separately?

Comment: The email is in my Gmail account, I want to be able to pull the text from the email and load it into my form in my application.

Comment: If you want to get email from your Gmail account, your best bet is to use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).